# Can useEffect be used to check whether the user token is present in the localStorage?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, jwt

I'm currently developing a Web application with authentication and I'd like to know what to do as a private route. Is it a good way to make a condition in my useEffect of one of my pages that I want private to know if the token is present or not?

ex:

```
import {useEffect} from "react";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";


function Dashboard() {

    const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!token) {
            navigate("/login")
        } else {
            fetchAPI ........
        }
    }, []);

    return (
    )
}

export default Dashboard
```

Comment: No, this will be checked only once after Dashboard component is rendered.

What then? You dont want to check it?

You have to check if token is not expired, right?

I would create separated component that would contains: <Navigate ...> element and use it in <Route> that wraps Dashboard.

Comment: @lukasmaska98 Do you have an example of your solution on StackOverflow? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to log the user out regardless of where he is then I suggest using the  `<outlet/>` component.

```js
import {useEffect} from "react";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";


function ProtectedRoute() {

    const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!token) {
            navigate("/login")
        } else {
            fetchAPI ........
        }
    }, []);

    return (
      <Outlet/>
    )
}

export default ProtectedRoute
```

Wherever your routes are being handled you'd essentially wrap the children inside of this `<ProtectedRoute/>` component. It would look something like this :

```
<Route element={<ProtectedRoute/>}>
 <Route path="/dashboard" element = {<Dashboard/>}
</Route>
```

By doing so you're essentially lessening the amount of code you're writing to do the same check. Every single time you navigate to a different page, this useEffect will get triggered. Naturally you can also start implementing the `useContext` and `createContext` hooks as to not have an insane amount of prop drilling going on. Another big help is that you can use the `ProtectedRoute` component as a layout component. If you have `sidebar` or `navbar` or whatever that needs to be displayed on every page, this is a great way as well. Hope this helps!